# how to add hyperlink for textview in layout main.xml

Tags: android-layout

I have used a customized list view in which i have added  4 TextView basically for 
name,address,city,telephone

Actually what i want when i click on the name it should navigate to browser.
same task i have achieved for telephone by using

android:autoLink="all" using layout in main.xml file.

Now here if i use url instead of name then it will become hyperlink
But for the name purpose what can i do so that name become as a hyperlink.

Please help me.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Hi all I got solution by myself, I put text view of name over the text view of URL and set the background color of name text view to white, So if any one click on the name text view it navigate to the given hotel's URL...  Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all I got solution by myself, I put text view of name over the text view of URL and set the background color of name text view to white, So if any one click on the name text view it navigate to the given hotel's URL... Thanks all